# xpages - Get rid of the fraction part of a currency

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I'm trying to get rid of the fraction part of a field stored in a Notes document as a `Number` field. In xPages it displays default as a Double which I then want to convert to Currency. When I use the standard Currency converter I can't get rid of the fraction part.

I tried to convert the Double to display `Integer Only` and programmatically converted the Double to intValue. This works fine as long as I don't use the Currency converter which seem to add the fractions no matter what. I guess this is because the `default fractionpart` is 2.

I guess one important clue is that I'm talking about Swedish currency.
In Sweden we display Currency in this pattern: `# ### ### kr`.
With punctuation as a space and the currency symbol AFTER the number.

I tried to use `Custom Converter - Pattern` like the Above example but then I don't get the punctuation correct.
So - what I'm trying to achieve is this:
`Example: 112 000 kr`
The Code Example will return this: `112 000,00 kr`

Of course I can do a String `Conversion-concatenation operation` to achieve this but the best would be if there's a way to get a hold of the `default fraction part` for the CurrencyCode and manipulate that..?
And to me it seems to be a `bug` because `"Display Integer Only"` seems to be disregarded.

Maybe there is a `pattern conversion` that I haven't found, that I can use?

Code Examples:

```
<xp:inputText value="#{document1.totSumCost}" id="totSumCost1">
        <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="kr" currencyCode="SEK" integerOnly="true" maxFractionDigits="0">
            </xp:convertNumber>
        </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

I "sort of" solved this myself in this somewhat disturbing way:

```
<xp:inputText value="#{document1.totSumCost}"
                    id="inputText2">
                        <xp:this.converter>
                <xp:convertNumber type="currency" integerOnly="true"
                    locale="sv" maxFractionDigits="0" currencySymbol=" ">
                </xp:convertNumber>
            </xp:this.converter>
                </xp:inputText>
                <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField6">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return " kr"}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:text>
```

Comment: I have also tried to use the param maxFractionDigits="0" - same boring result..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom converter:

```xml
<xp:this.converter>
    <xp:customConverter>
        <xp:this.getAsString><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            value.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1 ") + " kr"
            }]]></xp:this.getAsString>
        <xp:this.getAsObject><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            parseFloat(value.replace(" ", ""))
            }]]></xp:this.getAsObject>
    </xp:customConverter>
</xp:this.converter>
```

It converts numbers into Swedish currency format like
`123456789.12` --> `123 456 789 kr`
and parses it back to float.

If you want to save value as integer then use `parseInt()` instead of `parseFloat()`.

Answer (score 0):

Anders,

I have struggled with the same issue. I tried everything and could not find an elegant solution using a numeric type.  I eventually just created a custom converter that changed it to a string.

```
<xp:this.converter>
   <xp:customConverter  getAsObject="#{javascript:value}">
   <xp:this.getAsString><![CDATA[#{javascript:try{
       return "$" + numberWithCommas(value.toString());
   } catch(e){
       logError(e)
   }}]]></xp:this.getAsString>
   </xp:customConverter>
</xp:this.converter>
```

Below is the function reverenced above that we use throughout the app.

```
function numberWithCommas (x) {

var parts = x.toString().split(".");
parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
return parts.join(".");
}
```

I hope this helps.  While I was composing Knut's answer appeared which seems very similar.  Hopefully one of these will work for you.

Comment: Thanx Steve - Knut's sulotion is bit more clean I think.